# Batch: read file from path

Tags: batch-file, path, readfile

I want to read a .txt file using batch script.
Each line should be stored in a variable.

My problem: I have to give the command a file path to the .txt file. Unfortunately this hasn't worked so far. The solution is probably very simple, but I haven't found it yet.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ("%FilePath%backup\packs.txt") do (
         
  Set /a count+=1
  Set url[!count!]=%%a
  
)

echo %url[2]%
```

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because this is less of a typo and more of a weird quirk of the language that most people wouldn't know about unless they found it in the middle of the (very long) `for /?` documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`for /f` loops can process three different types of data - files, strings, and commands. Each of these is indicated differently when you call the `for` command.

A file is processed by not using quotes in the set area: `for /f %%A in (file.txt) do (`

A command is processed by using single quotes: `for /f %%A in ('find "abc" file.txt') do (`

A string is processed by using double quotes: `for /f %%A in ("hello world") do (`

Of course, sometimes you need to process a file with a space in the path, and that's when you'd use the `usebackq` option. This option will still process all three types of data, but the indicators will be different.

A file is processed by using double quotes: `for /f "usebackq" %%A in ("some file.txt") do (`

A command is processed by using backticks: `` for /f "usebackq" %%A in (`find "don't" file.txt`) do ( ``

A string is processed by using single quotes: `for /f "usebackq" %%A in ('19^" screen') do (`

---

Either removing the quotes from your file path or adding the `usebackq` option will set the variables for you.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "FilePath=.\test_path\"
set "count=0"

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%FilePath%backup\packs.txt") do (
    set /a count+=1
    set "url[!count!]=%%A"
)
echo %url[2]%
```